# CGI perl script can't write to file

Tags: apache, perl, centos, cgi

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Centos 7. I've spent a week on this problem and it's getting stressful (this is a test file, I'm setting up access for a third party to be able to write to a file on the server and created this to replicate the problem).

The script is running from /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/GzK8PhiWEfM9c4jZgyNrpYb5RtnD3ex6/test.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ":standard";

print "Content-type:text/html \n\n";

open (FILE, '>', "/home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/test.txt") or die ("Could not open the file for writing...$!");
print FILE "something";
close(FILE);
```

The error message says Internal Server Error, and the message in the error log says:

[Thu Sep 07 01:07:37.226029 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 28876] [client 2.221.192.244:56475] AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/GzK8PhiWEfM9c4jZgyNrpYb5RtnD3ex6/test.cgi' failed: /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/GzK8PhiWEfM9c4jZgyNrpYb5RtnD3ex6/test.cgi
[Thu Sep 07 01:07:37.226322 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 28876] [client 2.221.192.244:56475] End of script output before headers: test.cgi

This script runs fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
 
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 
print "Hello World!";
```

I can put test.txt in any folder and the same thing happens. The cgi-bin folder is owned by apache, but it still happens if it's owned by root and by sle, and all files are 777. The problem seems to be when it's trying to write to a file.

This is the virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost myipaddress:80 >
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com mydomain.com 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    <Directory "/home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/">
    Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +MultiViews
    Options FollowSymLinks
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup sle sle
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid sle sle
        #RGroups apache access
        RGroups @none
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine ON
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f sle@mydomain.com'
        php_admin_value mail.log /home/sle/.php/php-mail.log
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost myipaddress:443 >
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/cert/mydomain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/cert/mydomain.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/cert/mydomain.com.crt
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com mydomain.com 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/cgi-bin/">
    Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +MultiViews
    Options FollowSymLinks
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    UseCanonicalName OFF
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
        SuexecUserGroup sle sle
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid sle sle
        #RGroups apache access
        RGroups @none
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/mydomain.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/sle/domains/mydomain.com/private_html>
        php_admin_flag engine ON
        php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f sle@mydomain.com'
        php_admin_value mail.log /home/sle/.php/php-mail.log
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I moved the file to multiple locations, changed the ownership, changed the rights, added the  line in the virtualhost.

Comment: Exec format error.... Your file doesn't look like an executable to the server. Makes sure the `#!` are the first two bytes of the file (no spaces, no blank lines, no BOM, not UTF-16). Make sure there's no CR at the end of the line.

Comment: Does the same thing.

Comment: *"The problem seems to be when it's trying to write to a file."* What happens if you do not write to the file?

Comment: Also, what happens if you run the CGI script directly in Perl? `perl test.cgi`    I’d also throw an actual HTML output in your CGI too, otherwise you’re making an empty output. Your 2nd script shows a Hello World output, but your first (with the file stuff) does not.

Comment: Thanks everyone but I've actually managed to fix this. I removed the <Directory> statements in the virtualhost and added "Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl" to the htaccess file in cgi-bin, and it inexplicably worked.